# Отправка XML в Swagger

Tags: api, swagger

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся вот с какой проблемой: Пишу аннотацию для Swagger. Есть POST-запрос. В тело этого запроса хочу передать XML, но не знаю как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста.
Вот то, что есть сейчас:

```
/**
     * @OA\Post(
     *   tags={"khd"},
     *   path="/khd/reciever/updatedictionary?iblockcode={iblockcode}&propertycodetofilter={propertycodetofilter}",
     *   summary="Метод обновляет справочники КХД",
     *   @OA\Parameter(
     *     name="iblockcode",
     *     in="query",
     *     required=true,
     *     @OA\Schema(type="string")
     *   ),
     *   @OA\Parameter(
     *     name="propertycodetofilter",
     *     in="query",
     *     required=true,
     *     @OA\Schema(type="string")
     *   ),
     *   @OA\RequestBody(
     *     required=true,
     *     @OA\MediaType(
     *       mediaType="application/xml",
     *       @OA\Schema(
     *         type="object",
     *         @OA\Property(
     *           property="Item",
     *           type="object",
     *           @OA\Property(
     *             property="XMLID",
     *             type="string"
     *           )
     *         )
     *       )
     *     )
     *   )
     *   @OA\Response(response=200, description="OK"),
     *   @OA\Response(response=401, description="Unauthorized"),
     *   @OA\Response(response=404, description="Not Found")
     * )
     */
```

Но эта аннотация вообще не работает и Swagger ничего по ней не отображает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно?